# How to change the space between icons in React Navigation tab bar?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

The default tab bar looks like this, where each icon is evenly spaced. How could I change it to where the tab bars are closer together and centered?

**Default**

[image]

**Goal**

[image]

Messing with `justifyContent` in `tabBarOptions.style` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
tabBarStyle: {
        paddingHorizontal: 30,        
      },
```